# Windows command line search for exact extension with dir

Tags: windows, command-line, dir

When I do a search:

```
dir /b /s *.txt
```

I get all files/folders with the extension `.txt`. But I also get them when they have an extension like `.txtx`. How can I search for the exact extension?

Answer (score 38):

you can try this

```
dir  /s /b *.txt | findstr /v .txt.
```

or

```
dir  /s /b *.txt | findstr /e .txt
```

or

```
dir  /b *.txt | findstr  .txt$
```

Answer (score 4):

I can't figure out why it behaves like this, but this works: `dir /b /s .txt | findstr /e .txt`. Ugly but works.

Comment: probably because the dir-program expects filenames to be 8.3? Good it can handle other filenames, too...

Answer (score 0):

`dir C:\XML /s /b | findstr /e .xml > C:\XML\list.txt`

this works for me, just change the .xml extension to .txt

Answer (score 0):

Splitting the commands for better understanding:

```
dir /s /b 
     ^  ^
     |  |
     |  Displays a **bare** list of directories and files, with no additional information.
     |
      ~ Lists every occurrence of the specified file name within the 
        specified directory and all **subdirectories**.


findstr /e
        ^
        |
        Matches the text pattern if it is at the **end** of a line.
```