# dir command not current directory and filter

Tags: cmd

I am trying to list all the files with a specific extension but not the current directory.

Something like this

```
dir "C:\x y\test\" /b /s *.txt
```

but instead of the expected result it lists all the files from the specified directory AND the ones from the current directory.

Is there a way to get list the files with a specific extension from another directory than the current one

Comment: Go to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423935/windows-command-line-search-for-exact-extension-with-dir),
I think its a possible duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure, but i think it would be

```
dir "C:\some\path\*.txt" /b /s /a-d
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you look for something like

```
dir "c:\temp\*.txt"
```

As a fact I am not in **c:\temp**.

Answer (score 0):

How about [FORFILES](http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html)? It's more robust than the old "dir":

`FORFILES /P "Your/Path" /S /M *.txt`

*/p = The Path to search
*/s = Recurse into sub-folders